# copy to clipboard is not working in firefox 25

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

how can I implement "Clipboard" functionality in Firefox V25 . Even though I've changed in "about:config" the "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" to true as well as "clipboard.autocopy" to true , then also it's not working . Kindly give me a solution for this problem.

I used this piece of code for clipboard operation:

```
function copyToClipboardCrossbrowser(s) {           
s = document.getElementById(s).value;               

if( window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData )
{
        clipboardData.setData("Text", s);
}           
else{
       // You have to sign the code to enable this or allow the action in about:config by changing
       //user_pref("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support", true);
       netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

       var clip = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
       if (!clip) return;

       // create a transferable

       var trans = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
       if (!trans) return;

       // specify the data we wish to handle. Plaintext in this case.
       trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');

       // To get the data from the transferable we need two new objects
       var str = new Object();
       var len = new Object();

       var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);

       str.data= s;        

       trans.setTransferData("text/unicode",str, str.data.length * 2);

       var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;              
       if (!clip) return false;
       clip.setData(trans,null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);      
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this feature is not supported any more. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977068#answer-500083. Maybe making some noise in a Firefox bug will help us get a (safe) solution.

Answer (score 0):

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect')

do not work in current version of firefox because of security considarations - seaching for a solution myself!